# Avoid sql injection with connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4

If a query can't be efficiently expressed using ActiveRecord, how to safely use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` when interpolating passed `params` attributes?

```
connection.execute "... #{params[:search]} ..."
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the methods in [ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html).

You do have to be slightly careful as they are protected and therefore only readily available for `ActiveRecord::Base` subclasses.

Within a model class you could do something like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def bespoke_query(params)
    query = sanitize_sql(['select * from somewhere where a = ?', params[:search]])
    connection.execute(query)
  end

end
```

You can `send` the method to try it out on the console too:

```
> MyModel.send(:sanitize_sql, ["Evening Officer ?", "'Dibble'"])
=> "Evening Officer '\\'Dibble\\''"
```

Comment: I think `query = sanitize_sql('select * from somewhere where a = ?', params[:search])` should be `query = sanitize_sql(['select * from somewhere where a = ?', params[:search]])`

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord has a **sanitize** method that allows you to clean the query first.
Perhaps it's something you can look into: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize

I'd be very careful inserting parameters directly like that though.
What problem are you experiencing, that you cannot use ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions from `ActiveRecord::Base` to sanitize your sql query. E.g. `sanitize_sql_array`. As mentioned in other answers they are protected, but that's possible to get around without having to deal with inheritance.

`sanitize_sql_array` accepts an array of strings where the first element is the query and the subsequent elements will replace `?` characters in the query.

```rb
query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? OR first_name = ?'
id = 1
name = 'Alice'

sanitized_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [query, id, name])
response = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_query)
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation for your answer. Code-only answers don't provide insightful information.

Comment: There's no need to use `send`, could just do `ActiveRecord::Base. sanitize_sql_array(...)`